# Combining two Excel Formulas into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I have two formulas that work correctly by themselves and am not sure how to combine them into one formula.

1st formula:

```vb
=COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,">=1/1/2020",'FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,"<=12/31/2020")
```

is to count by date range.

2nd formula:

```vb
=COUNTIFS(B10:B4821,10086143)
```

is to count based of a macro for colored cells.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by combine the two? You want a count of this + this?

Comment: Yes Yisroel i need to look at the data from formula 1 and see how many from that year are a certain color.

Comment: COUNTIFS allows for multiple conditions, what have you tried?

Comment: =COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,">=1/1/2020",'FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,"<=12/31/2020")&(COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!A8:A2500,9359529))

Comment: =COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,">=1/1/2020",'FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,"<=12/31/2020")*(COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!A8:A2500,9359529))

Comment: =COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,">=1/1/2020",'FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!D8:D2500,"<=12/31/2020")+(COUNTIFS('FFRCA - FMLA Archive'!A8:A2500,9359529))

Comment: @MeredithCarver, you need to add (and a screenshot) of an example how your sheet is. It sounds to me like you need to simply add a 3rd range and criteria to the formula, something like ```=COUNTIFS(D2:D2500,">=1/1/2020",D2:D2500,"<=12/31/2020",B2:B2500,10086143)```

Comment: I added a link so you can see kind of what i am looking at

Comment: So in your example your result should be **1** (since there is only 1 example in 2020 with that color)?

Comment: So i should have 2 for 2020, 2 for 2021 and 1 for 2023. I need to account for both colors and the date range.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are very unclear. You are looking for more than one formula to account for different years? And you want to count the cells regardless of what color? From your question it sounded like you are looking for a single formula, so my question is what result do you want that single formula to be and why that result?

Comment: I am so sorry if i am being unclear that is not my intentions. So i am trying to separate the date out by year, so that is my date range 1/1/2020 - 12/31/2020, and then i need to know how many cells during that date range are the two colors that i need. See on my workbook i have 3 other colors, but i do not want to pull the data for those colors at this time just for the yellow and orange colors.

Comment: Does something like ```=COUNTIFS(D:D,">=1/1/2020",D:D,"<=12/31/2020",B:B,9359529)+COUNTIFS(D:D,">=1/1/2020",D:D,"<=12/31/2020",B:B,10086143)``` work for you?

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much Yisroel

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to combine/sum two `COUNTIFS`, each having the criteria match for the range and one color. This will basically first count all in the date range that have color 1 and then add the count of all in the date range with the 2nd color.

Your example data (ranges used) is a bit unclear, but it would be something like:
`=COUNTIFS(D:D,">=1/1/2020",D:D,"<=12/31/2020",B:B,9359529)+COUNTIFS(D:D,">=1/1/2020",D:D,"<=12/31/2020",B:B,10086143)`